# "Simple" RESTful API using node/mongo/express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am completely new to server side javascript so any help would really be appreciated.

I recently followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p-x6WdwaJco to build a simple RESTful API with node.js mongodb and express. The tutorial also uses a library called node-restful https://github.com/baugarten/node-restful.
First of all I built a server.js in the root directory:

```
// Dependencies
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// Mongo DB
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/rest_test');

// Express
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Routes
app.use('/api', require('./routes/api'));

var test = require('./routes/api');

// Start Server
app.listen(3000);
console.log('API is running on port 3000')
```

Then I created api.js in root/routes

```
// Dependencies
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

// Models
var Product = require('../models/product');

// Routes
Product.methods(['get', 'put', 'post', 'delete']);
Product.register(router, '/products');

// Return router
module.exports = router;
```

Finally I created a file called product.js within root/models:

```
// Dependencies
var express = require('express');
var restful = require('node-restful');
var mongoose = restful.mongoose;

// Schema
var productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    sku: String,
    price: Number,
});

// Return model
module.exports = restful.model('Products', productSchema);
```

This is where my issue is(i think) - the server runs fine until I attempt to use .methods() and .register() on mongoose.Schema() from api.js. It keeps telling me that .methods is undefined in Product.

I have been through the tutorial over and over and can see nothing wrong with my code. All libraries seemed to have installed correctly. Mongo is running...

I have a feeling that mongoose.Schema is not registering properly but have no idea why as everything seems to be as it is in the tutorial - there are no similar complaints on the tutorial -  so I can only assume this is "my problem" but I just can't see where I've gone wrong....

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied your code exactly and then was able to run it without any issues. So this most likely means there's some issue in your local environment. Most likely an old/outdated package.

In your root directory, create a file called *package.json* with the following contents:

```
{
  "name": "stackoverflow-30492214",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.12.4",
    "express": "^4.12.4",
    "mongoose": "^3.9.7",
    "node-restful": "^0.1.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {}
}
```

And then, in the same directory, in your terminal run `npm clean && npm install`. This should download/install/build dependencies as defined by the package.json. Once done, try running the server again `node server.js`. You might get a warning about the mongoose package being an unstable version, but you shouldn't see any .method() or .register() undefined errors.

Comment: Thanks for the reply :) --- No luck though. I even created a new root folder copied the js files over and did a fresh npm install with the package json you gave me - I got the "unstable mongoose warning" and right below the same error - methods is not defined in Product. I had an issue downloading the dev version of mongodb so I downloaded the binary version instead - not sure if that has anything to do with it... Thanks

Comment: hm... are you able to connect to mongodb via the command line? In your terminal, try running `mongo` then, enter `db` should list any local db's you have. then confirm you can write: `db.foobar.insert({foo: 'bar'})` and check if it's there `db.foobar.find()`. Also.. what version of node are you using? `node --version`

Comment: yeah everything seems to be working fine, can write to the DB, - node -v 0.12.4

Comment: Okay sorry it works... I'm not sure what the problem was originally, but your package.json seems to have done the trick. Didn't have much time with it yesterday... Thanks very much for your time.

Comment: Actually I can now clarify ( although it's probably stupid ) I was not running mongo db - I was only running mongo d.  Ha, Problem Solved. Thanks again